# How do I stack 3-D arrays in a grouped pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe that consists of two columns: a column of string identifiers and a column of 3-D arrays. The arrays have been grouped by the ID.  How can I stack all the arrays for each group so that there is a single stacked array for each ID? The code I have is as follows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'IDs': ids})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'arrays':arrays})

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
grouped = df['arrays'].groupby(df['IDs'])
```

(I attempted `np.dstack(grouped)`, but this was unsuccessful.)

Comment: I don't know if it matters in this case or not, but a general 'unsuccessful' description does not help us understand your problem   A [mcve] might also help.

Comment: A couple of leading questions.  What is `grouped`?  It's not a `Series` or `DataFrame`, though it may contain one or the other.  `np.dstack` takes numpy arrays, or things it can make into arrays, and returns an array.  It is a numpy operation, not a pandas one.  When you throw `grouped` at it, what exactly are you passing it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

```
df.groupby('IDs')['arrays'].apply(np.dstack).to_frame().reset_index()
```

It will [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) the `np.dstack(...)` function to each group of arrays sharing an ID.

The `apply()` function returns a `pd.Series` (with IDs as index), so we then use `to_frame()` to create a DataFrame from it and `reset_index()` to put IDs back as a column.

> (Note: The documentation for `apply()` talks about using `agg()` for efficiency, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible to use `agg()` with a function that returns an ndarray, such as `np.dstack`. In that case, `agg()` wants to treat that array as multiple objects, as a series, rather than as a single object... My attempts with it resulted in an exception saying "function does not reduce".)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your solution accomplished exactly what I was trying to do, and the accompanying explanation is much appreciated.